# JPA - defining multi-column unique constraints

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

Is it possible using JPA to define multiple unique constraints.

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    long id;

     String name;

     MyEnum type;

}
```

Foo.id should be unique as should combinations of {Foo.name, Foo.type}.
Ex.
id, name, type
1, "name1", "type1"
2, "name1", "type2"
3, "name1", "type1" // error duplicate of id = 1

How do I achieve this using JPA annotations?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the `uniqueConstraints` attribute of the `Table` annotation:

```
@Table(name = "FOO", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"NAME", "TYPE"})
})
```

Comment: Oracle will report a column not found if the property does not have its column name attribute explicitly specified in the Column annotation.